Может ли инфинитив обозначить (в значении определить) указывать словесно на сами предметы, а не только на их характеристики?
Обозначить Определять (определить) что-л., называя кого-л., указывая что-л.
Входит ли в это понятие данное определение?
То есть (дать понять, о каком конкретно предмете в тексте идёт речь)  например, дать понять, что рука - это рука, а мяч - это мяч?

Насколько точно инфинитив должен указывать на собственно предмет? У существительного рука немало синонимов: кисть/десница/протез (руки) /манипулятор робота/почерк (рука) мастера / руки загребущие / рука Москвы.
Уточним вопрос. Инфинитив «наследить» указывает только на существительное «след» или еще и на «улика»?

Инфинитив "уличать" указывает на существительное "улика", но в качестве улики может оказаться не только "предмет", но и "обстоятельство".

guaranteen, здравствуйте, здесь вопрос не в том должен ли он указывать или нет, а может ли, исходя из своего словарного значения. Так может или нет?
